# How to use the token information from Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential to build cookies in a request sent to a webapi endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, google-api, openid

From a WPF application, the user authenticates with Google with this code:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
...
public void Authenticate()
{
    UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = "myClientId",
            ClientSecret = "myClientSecret"
        },
        new[] { "email", "openid" },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None).Result;
}
```

This works and the `UserCredential` object contains the authenticated token:

[image]

I would like to embed this token information in a web request made with an `HttpClient` in order to call a webapi endpoint, is that possible and how?

I think the request must use some cookies to inform the server that it is authenticated, but I don't know which ones exactly.

The endpoint on the server-side validates that the user is authenticated with the help of IdentityServer:

```
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
if (result?.Succeeded != true)
{
    throw new Exception("External authentication error");
}
```

Comment: What api end point do you want to use this with exactly? techncally you only need the refresh token then you can request a new access token when ever you need.  Any google api endpoint just needs the access token to make the request valid

Comment: Hi @DaImTo and thanks for your reply. The api end point I am accessing is one from a web server backend that I coded. That api end point validates that the request was authenticated with the Google external provider with IdentityServer and the piece of code above. Unfortunately I don't know what the `AuthenticateAsync` checks for that, I suppose standard authentication cookies set. That is why I would like to embed the token information obtained from Google in the request calling my web api.